# Deployment of a Polymer 2.0 app on Apache httpd or tomcat? How?

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have written a nice polymer app, that works like a charm when running inside the development server (polymer serve). Even bookmarked URLs and so on work.

For production I need to deploy it as a web context on a Tomcat application server. Another option is a Apache httpd server. This requires someway to configure URL rewriting, so everything works in this context, too.

Sadly, Google hasn't provided any useful link. So, maybe on of you guys has a handy solution for this problem? Anything is highly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?
usually running `polymer build` and then putting the resulting files on the webserver is enough. For a simple rounting example you can take a look at my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829418/polymer-app-route-intercept-refresh-page/48921750#48921750

Comment: @daKmoR This solved my issue or inspired my solution. I implemented it using urlRewriteFilter for Tomcat, but it uses more or less the same rules.

Comment: awesome :) maybe you can share your configuration for Tomcat so that other people can find it as well :)